# How to refer to MySQL sum case cells in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following MySQL script which pulls out exactly the data I need:

```
SELECT gate,
     sum(case when grade = 'Echo4' then 1 else 0 end) echo4,
     sum(case when grade = 'Echo5' then 1 else 0 end) echo5,
     sum(case when grade = 'Echo6' then 1 else 0 end) echo6,
     sum(case when grade = 'Echo7' then 1 else 0 end) echo7,
count(*) total
from MyTable
group by gate with rollup
```

I want to display the data in an HTML table, which I know how to construct if I knew how to refer to the cells that are displayed. My output looks like this:

```
gate        echo4   echo5   echo6   echo7   total
Center      14      32      3       1       50
Right       5       27      20      8       60
Left        2       37      12      0       51
Middle      4       12      5       0       21
East        0       9       2       0       11
West        0       32      11      1       44
North       1       29      9       0       39
South       8       61      29      0       98
HQ          1       1       1       0       3
NULL        35      240     92      10      377
```

In PHP, how do I refer to the intersection of 'Center' and 'Echo4'? ... 'Center' and 'Echo5'? etc.

Comment: row['echo4'] and you generate it in a while loop

Comment: You could, for example, when fetching rows, append them to an array which is _indexed_ by `gate` like `$rows[$current_row['gate']] = $current_row;` Then it becomes easy to access them like `$rows['North']['echo5']`  Without any specific PHP code, I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: please state the structure of the desired html table; also show the code you have tried and state how the results differed from your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to store things in terms of an array ... I'll be super generic, but should get the point across.

```
$query = '
    SELECT gate,
        CAST(SUM(CASE grade WHEN 'Echo4' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INTEGER) AS echo4,
        CAST(SUM(CASE grade WHEN 'Echo5' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INTEGER) AS echo5,    
        CAST(SUM(CASE grade WHEN 'Echo6' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INTEGER) AS echo6,
        CAST(SUM(CASE grade WHEN 'Echo7' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS INTEGER) AS echo7,
        COUNT(*) AS total
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY gate WITH ROLLUP
';

$grade = array();
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)) {
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $gate, $echo4, $echo5, $echo6, $echo7, $total);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
        $grade[$gate]['echo4'] = $echo4;
        $grade[$gate]['echo5'] = $echo5;
        $grade[$gate]['echo6'] = $echo6;
        $grade[$gate]['echo7'] = $echo7;
        $grade[$gate]['total'] = $total;
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

Then you can reference it later by gate and position:

```
echo $grade['Center']['echo4'];
```

Should do the trick. A note is that this with bound statements, but you should be able to change it for the standard `mysqli` statement. A note that I updated your query to be more performant by making your `CASE` statements value instead of expression, and explicitly `CAST`ing them.

Answer (score 1):

For a complete answer.

We first connect to the database, then we run our query and fetch the data into an object. Then we iterate all the results and outputs the data.

```
<?php
    try {  
      $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=databaseName", "username", "password");  
      $DBH->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );  
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Ups. Something went wrong " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    //Next, do your query
    $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT gate,
                                 sum(case when grade = 'Echo4' then 1 else 0 end) echo4,
                                 sum(case when grade = 'Echo5' then 1 else 0 end) echo5,
                                 sum(case when grade = 'Echo6' then 1 else 0 end) echo6,
                                 sum(case when grade = 'Echo7' then 1 else 0 end) echo7,
                            count(*) total
                            from MyTable
                            group by gate with rollup");  

    //Set the fetch mode, i like objects.
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);  
      //Lets do some html.
    echo '<table>
            <tr>
                <td>Gate</td>
                <td>echo4</td>
                <td>echo5</td>
                <td>echo6</td>
                <td>echo7</td>
                <td>total</td>
            </tr>';

    //Lets output the result.
    foreach( $STH->fetchAll() as $object)
        echo '<tr>
                <td>' . $object->gate . '</td>
                <td>' . $object->echo4 . '</td>
                <td>' . $object->echo5 . '</td>
                <td>' . $object->echo6 . '</td>
                <td>' . $object->echo7 . '</td>
                <td>' . ( $object->echo4 + $object->echo5 + $object->echo6 + $object->echo7 ) . '</td>
            </tr>';
    }  

    //Lets close that table.
    echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to get the intersection, as you're going to get rows from your database query, and gate will be a field in that.

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo '<tr><th>'.$result['gate'].'</th>...other columns...<td>'.$result['Echo4'].'</td></tr>'
}
```